# Unransackable attributes for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, ransack

To exclude some attributes from search and sorting I add following to my model

```
UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES = %w[id created_at updated_at section] 

def self.ransackable_attributes auth_object = nil
    (column_names - UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES) + _ransackers.keys
end
```

Two of my models use this, so what is the way to keep my code DRY and write this method once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done next way:

1) uncomment  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras) in 'config/application.rb'
and change 'extras' to 'lib'

2) in 'lib' directory create 'ransackable_attributes.rb':

```
module RansackableAttributes
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        def self.ransackable_attributes auth_object = nil
            (column_names - self::UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES) + _ransackers.keys
        end
    end

end
```

3) Add 'include' to models

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
    include RansackableAttributes
```

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    include RansackableAttributes
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I wanted to share my way of handling this in the event you do not want to have UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES in all your models. I have created an initializer which extends Ransacks Module of ActiveRecord::Base

```
module Ransack
  module Adapters
    module ActiveRecord
      module Base
        attr_accessor :_spare
        def spare_ransack(*attribs)
          self._spare = attribs.map{|a| a.to_s}
        end
        def spareables
          self._spare ||= []
          column_names - self._spare
        end
        def ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
          spareables + _ransackers.keys
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use

```
MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  spare_ransack :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :section
end
```

And these attributes will not be ransackable. I like this method because it will allow you to set them conditionally.

**Edit**

Although frowned upon as Class Magic this does work for those of you that don't mind

```
def spare_ransack(*attribs)
  self._spare = attribs.map do |a| 
    case a.to_sym
      #remove time_stamp fields 
        when :time_stamps
          ["created_at","updated_at"]
      #requires spare_ransack to be called after associations in the file
        when :association_keys
          reflect_on_all_associations.select{|a| a.macro == :belongs_to}.collect{|a| a.options[:foreign_key] || "#{a.name}_id"}
      #remove primary key field 
        when :primary
          primary_key
        else
          a.to_s
    end
  end.flatten
end

MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  spare_ransack :primary,:time_stamps, :section
end
```

Comment: Your welcome although please know this methodology is frowned upon by ernie (creator of ransack). I have also expanded the implementation see update